# Why doesn't 'while' work the same as 'for' with a continue staement

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

If I try the the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i < 5:
        continue
    print(i)
```

it will print the numbers 6-10.
But the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    while i < 5:
        continue
    print(i)
```

will never terminate. 
It seems that the while loop *doesn't increment i*. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: the _outer_ loop increments it, but the _inner_ loop doesn't.

Comment: A `while` loop does not increment, and keeps looping as long as the condition holds.

Comment: The point is, `continue` continues the execution of the _current_ loop.

Comment: As the previous commenter indicates, your first example has one loop, and your second example has two loops, and the `continue` statement in the second example will keep the inner loop going indefinitely.

Comment: Okay. Thanks all, I get it now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `while` loop is a code structure with a condition. As long as the condition is satisfied, it will keep looping. Furthermore a `while` loop does *nothing* else (this in contrast to the `for` loop that reads the next item into the variable).

Furthermore a `while` loop is a *loop*. The `continue` statement binds with the closest loop. So in your second code statement, the `continue` will let the code perform a new iteration on the `while` loop.

Since your `while` loop does not changes the `i`, and the `continue` will let the `while` loop (not the `for` loop) perform a new loop, it will thus keep executing the `while` loop.

That being said, both code fragments are not elegant. You can simply use a `range(..)` statement with two parameter to state the *start* value:

```
for i in range(6, 10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I only used the code above as a simple example. I'm not a complete noob, although retrospectively, the question sure makes me seem like one XD

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR `while loop` *!=* `if statement`**

You have a misunderstanding of how these loop structures work.

A `for-loop` will loop through a `variable` in an `iterable` such as `range`. When it reaches the end of the `iterable` or encounters a `break` or `return`, it will jump out of the `loop`.

A `while` loop continuously runs whilst the condition is `True` or it encounters a `break` or `return`.

In your case, when the program reaches the first loop of the `for-loop`, `i` is `0`. Then you enter a `while` loop with the condition `i < 5`.

This condition is `True` (as `0` is `< 5`) so the `loop` runs.

In here, you call `continue`. This keyword tells Python to move to the next loop and escape the current loop. So in this context, as the `while` loop is the current `loop`, Python jumps to the next loop in the `while` loop.

Here, we once again evaluate the condition: `i < 5` and once again this is `True`. As you can see, we are back to `2` paragraphs above! Thus, an infinite `loop` has been created and the program will never end.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: or encounters a `break`. That works too

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That is actually what I meant to write! I was thinking of `break` and I guess `return` works too!